# Build a data frame from the existing data frame which has the distinct id

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like in the figure.

I have multiple id with different columns.

I want to build another dataframe that only has the distinct id and also the dataframes has all the columns for that id.

could you help me with that? Thank you so much

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [2, 3, 3,2,1]
df['c2'] = [1, 10, 6, 7, 4]
df['c3'] = [11, 23, 9, 10,23]
print(df)

dfn = pd.DataFrame()
dfn['id'] = [2, 3,1]
dfn['c2'] = [1, 10, 4]
dfn['c3'] = [11, 23, 23]
dfn['c4'] = [7, 6,  0]
dfn['c5'] = [10, 9,  0]
dfn
```

[The first one is that I have and the second one is that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8hmm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_index` / `unstack` at starting point of the transformation to flatten your dataframe. You can execute the following code step-by-step to follow the transformation to your final dataframe:

```
out = (
    df.set_index('id').rename_axis(columns='col')
      .stack().rename('val').reset_index()
      .assign(col=lambda x: x.groupby('id').cumcount().add(2))
      .pivot_table('val', 'id', 'col', fill_value=0, sort=False)
      .add_prefix('c').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   id  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   2   1  11   7  10
1   3  10  23   6   9
2   1   4  23   0   0
```

Comment: I know the column names are not the same as yours but is it really important?. As workaround, you can `add(2)` instead of `add(1)`. So does it solve your problem?

Comment: Your `c2` and `c3` columns seem to be mixed (relative to OP's desired output).

Comment: You are right. This is the problem of `melt`... I think I need to you use `set_index`/`unstack`

Comment: @fsl. I updated my answer related to your comment. If you want to check :)

Comment: Good one. I had already upvoted btw.

Comment: @corralien Thanks. It works for me. However, for the sort=false in the pivot_table, it gives an error that is unexpected input... and one quick qustion, could you please tell me that what is this part do? cumcount().add(2))

Comment: `cumcount().add(2)` is to create an index for new columns. `cumcount` starts from 0 so I add 2 to get names like 'col2', 'col3', ... If the column name doesn't matter, just remove `.add`. Just for testing, replace 2 by 100 and you will understand :)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach:

```
df.filter(regex='c\d+', axis=1) \
    .groupby(df['id'], sort=False).apply(np.ravel).apply(pd.Series) \
    .rename(lambda x: f"c{x + 2}", axis=1).reset_index().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   id    c2    c3   c4    c5
0   1   4.0  23.0  0.0   0.0
1   2   1.0  11.0  7.0  10.0
2   3  10.0  23.0  6.0   9.0
```

Comment: Nice method too. +1. The problem here is the lost of dtype. Use `sort=False` with `groupby` to keep the order of `id`.

Comment: Thanks @fsl. It works for the example which I provided. However, it not work on my data set. My data set has multiple columns with name "value_1" until "value_200". I dont know why it can not works. the output is only shows the columns of "id".

Comment: Indeed, @Corralien I missed that. Thanks for the tip with the sorting.

Comment: @Cheese, naive question, but did you change the `regex` part to reflect your column names, i.e. `regex='value_\d+'`?

Comment: @fsl It is not naive question for me:) no. I did not and now that I have change that, it works for me. Thank you. I don't know how to chose the best answer now.

Comment: Glad it worked. That's fine, you can leave the originally accepted answer.

Comment: I can answer for you @fsi ;-) I preserve the datatype (int64) of column values :-) lol

Comment: Lol. True that. :)